XSRF-TOKEN won't change a second time
I'm creating a single page form that won't reload the page after submitting the form. I'm currently at the stage where I first get messages like I filled something in incorrectly (that's ok), but then when I click the button again, I get err 419. I noticed, in Applications DevTool, that the first time both XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session change, but the next time I submit the form, only laravel_session changes.How to prevent it and how to fix it? Thank you
Step by Step:

I come to the page, of course I have a new laravel_sesion + XSRF token

I click on the form - a new laravel_session + XSRF token is then generated

I click on the form again - only laravel_session is generated
 @section('content')
 @include('notifications')
 @if(config('register.register'))
     <div style="text-align: center">
         {!! Html::form('POST', route('auth.register.register'))->id('registerForm')->class('form-horizontal')->open() !!}

         @if($hash)
             <div class="form-group">
                 {!! Html::label('reflink_hash', trans('translate.promo_code_label_user'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'promo_code_label') !!}
                 <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::text('reflink_hash', $hash)->class('form-control')->readonly()->attribute('data-translate-key', 'promo_code_placeholder_user') !!}</div>
             </div>
         @endif

         <div class="form-group">
             {!! Html::label('username', trans('translate.login'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'login') !!}
             <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::text('username')->class('form-control')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'login_placeholder') !!}</div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             {!! Html::label('password', trans('translate.password'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'password') !!}
             <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::password('password')->class('form-control')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'password_placeholder') !!}</div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             {!! Html::label('password_confirmation', trans('translate.confirm_password'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'confirm_password') !!}
             <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::password('password_confirmation')->class('form-control')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'password_placeholder') !!}</div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             {!! Html::label('email', trans('translate.email'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'email') !!}
             <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::email('email')->class('form-control')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'email_placeholder') !!}</div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             {!! Html::label('code', trans('translate.code_delete_char'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'code_delete_char') !!}
             <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::text('code')->class('form-control')->attribute('maxlength', '7') !!}</div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             {!! Html::label('pin', trans('translate.pin'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'pin') !!}
             <div class="col-sm-8">{!! Html::text('pin')->class('form-control')->attribute('maxlength', '4')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'pin_placeholder') !!}</div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8" style="width: 304px; margin:0 auto 10px auto">
                 {!! Html::label('captcha', trans('translate.captcha'))->class('control-label col-sm-3')->attribute('data-translate-key', 'captcha') !!}
                 {!! app('captcha')->display() !!}
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="checkbox">
                 <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                     <span data-translate-key="terms">{{ trans('translate.accept_terms') }}</span>
                     <a href="{{ route('main.rules.index') }}"><b data-translate-key="tos">{{ trans('translate.tos') }}</b></a>
                     <span data-translate-key="terms">{{ trans('translate.terms_end') }}</span>
                 </label>
             </div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" name="create-account" value=" "><span data-translate-key="register">{{ trans('translate.register_me') }}</span></button>
         </div>

         {!! Html::form()->close() !!}
     </div>
 @else
     <div class="alert" data-translate-key="registration_unavailable">{{ trans('translate.registration_unavailable') }}</div>
 @endif

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#registerForm').on('submit', function(event) {
             event.preventDefault(); // Zabrání obnovení stránky

             $.ajax({
                 url: $(this).attr('action'),
                 method: 'POST',
                 data: $(this).serialize(),
                 headers: {
                     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 },
                 success: function(response) {
                     if (response.status === 'success') {
                         alert(response.message); // Úspěšná registrace
                         // Přesměrování nebo aktualizace UI
                     } else {
                         alert(response.message); // Zobrazení chyby
                     }
                 },
                 error: function(xhr) {
                     alert('Err');
                 }
             });
         });
     });
 </script>



Update:
I tried updating, but now what happens is:

Both are updated correctly once (XSRF + laravel_session)

XSRF is updated once but then laravel_session twice (which is already wrong - ERR 419)
 <script>
 function reloadCsrfToken() {
     $.ajax({
         url: '/refresh-csrf',
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(response) {
             const newToken = response.token;

             // Aktualizujte meta tag
             $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', newToken);

             $('input[name="_token"]').val(newToken);

             console.log('CSRF token byl úspěšně aktualizován.');
         },
         error: function() {
             console.log('Nepodařilo se aktualizovat CSRF token.');
         }
     });
 }

 function initializeRegisterForm() {
     $('#registerForm').off('submit').on('submit', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({
             url: $(this).attr('action'),
             method: 'POST',
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             headers: {
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
             },
             success: function(response) {
                 if (response.status === 'success') {
                     alert(response.message);
                 } else {
                     alert(response.message);
                 }
             },
             error: function(xhr) {
                 alert('Err');
             }
         });
     });

     $('#registerForm').submit();
 }

 $('#registerButton').on('click', function() {
     reloadCsrfToken();
     initializeRegisterForm();
 });




$(document).ready(function() is only red and executed once. Not 100% sure, but therein may be the problem you encounter. Make it a function outside of document ready and call it from inside the event.

@DimitriMostrey i tried change, but it still broken :/

Pity. There is a session() method called session()->regenerateToken(); you can basically call from anywhere (except javascript I guess). Could that be of any help? The session token is accessible as session('_token') or have a look at class where the magic happens: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php. What does url: '/refresh-csrf' do? This looks like a route you created yourself.

Everytime a mutating request (POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE) is sent, the CSRF token changes. After you executed the register request (successful or not), the CSRF token changed. You need to reflect that in your code.
From Laravel documentation :

Laravel stores the current CSRF token in an encrypted XSRF-TOKEN cookie that is included with each response generated by the framework. You can use the cookie value to set the X-XSRF-TOKEN request header.

Libraries like axios can automatically intercept those mutating requests and keep the token for the next request.
